# How can I stub a jQuery method with Sinon?

Tags: jquery, ember.js, coffeescript, sinon, chai

I have the following code in an Ember View:

```
  postRender: ->
    @_super()
    @$().tooltipster({
      content: @$().data('tooltip')
      contentAsHTML: true
    })
```

I'm trying to test that `tooltipster()` is called when `postRender()` executes but I'm having some trouble spying on `tooltipster()` with Sinon. Here's my spec so far:

```
  describe 'postRender', ->
    it 'initializes tooltips', ->
      spy = sinon.spy(view.$(), 'tooltipster')
      view.postRender()
      spy.should.be.calledOnce
      view.$().tooltipster.restore()
```

But that complains that `view.$()` is undefined.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're supposed to send in a function, not the response of the function to sinon's spy.

```
spy = sinon.spy(view.$, 'tooltipster')
```

That being said, it's unlikely the `$` method will be defined on the view not following the proper conventions.  And you aren't really testing Ember's ability to set up the $ method, so you can set it all up on your own if needs be.  Something like this:

```
var test = false;

view.$ = function(){
  return {
    data: function(attr){
      return 'something';
    },
    tooltipster: function(hash){
      test = true;
    }
  };
}
view.postRender();
assert(test, 'tooltipster should have been called, and test is true');
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery object gets methods like `$().css()` from the `$.fn` object. [jQuery plugins like tooltipster are registered there, too](https://github.com/iamceege/tooltipster/blob/master/js/jquery.tooltipster.js#L1113). Spying on `$.fn.tooltipster` is what you want to do:

```
spy = sinon.spy view.$.fn, 'tooltipster'
view.postRender()
spy.should.be.calledOnce
spy.restore() # or view.$.fn.tooltipster.restore()
```